# Locus of Z as cartesian equation

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Could you please help with this locus problem? I think I am aiming for a cartesian equation in terms of $x$ and $y$ that may look like a circle equation e.g. $(x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2$ but I'm not sure.

> Given there is a locus of $z$ such that
>   $$\frac{|z-12j|}{|z+36|}=3,$$
>   then $|z-12j| = 3|z+36|$.

Now I want to write the locus of $z$ as a cartesian equation in terms of $x$ and $y$. Let $z=x+yj$. 
$$\begin{align*}
|x+yj - 12j| &= 3|x+yj+36|\\
|x+(y-12)j| &= 3|(x+36)+yj|
\end{align*}$$
Where should I go from here?

Comment: Square both sides and use the fact that $|a+bj|^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then simplify.

Comment: You can type equations directly, instead of creating images and then linking to them. In fact, it's better not to rely on images.

Comment: Thanks @ArturoMagidin I'd like to learn how to type equations, is there some instructions for that somewhere on here?

Comment: @NSDigital: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773/742) should get you started.

Comment: Note: $(x+a)^2 + (y+b)^2$ is not an equation. A dead giveaway that it is not an equation is the fact that it does not have an equal sign in it.

Answer (score 2):

Just as with real numbers, where squaring removes absolute value bars, you can do something similar with complex numbers. Remember that if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers (as your $x$ and $y$ appear to be, though you never actually *said so*), we have
$$|a+bj| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2},$$
so that $|a+bj|^2 = a^2+b^2$.
So from
$$|x + (y-12)j| = 3|(x+36)+yj|$$
we get
$$|x+(y-12)j|^2 = 9|(x+36)+yj|^2$$
and whence to
$$\begin{align*}
x^2 + (y-12)^2 &= 9\Bigl((x+36)^2 + y^2\Bigr)\\
x^2 + y^2 - 24y + 144 &= 9\Bigl( x^2 + 72x + 1296 + y^2\Bigr)\\
0 &= 8x^2 + 648x + 8y^2 + 24y + 11520.
\end{align*}$$
Since both sides of your original equation necessarily have the same sign, there is no problem with the possible introduction of spurious solutions, so you'll get a specific conic out of this equation.